# how to set total of a particular column in footer in gridview in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to set total of a particular column in a gridview.

My code is:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
     <HeaderTemplate>
         Amount
     </HeaderTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="lblAmt" HeaderText="Amount" runat="server" 
              Text='<%# Eval("Amount")%>' Visible="true">
         </asp:Label>
     </ItemTemplate>
     <FooterTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="lblTotalAmt" runat="server" />
     </FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and then:

```
decimal totProfit = 0M;
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
     {
          Label lblAmt = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblAmt");
          decimal Profitprice = Decimal.Parse(lblAmt.Text);
          totProfit += Profitprice;
     }
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
     {
          Label lblTotalAmt = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblTotalAmt");
          lblTotalAmt.Text = totProfit.ToString();
     }
 }
```

But error came like:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

Answer (score 2):

There is an error that's recognized by MS during integer conversions that may be coming into play here (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942460)

The other option, is to ensure that it's a number in the 'Amount' field.

```
decimal totProfit = 0M;
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Label lblAmt = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblAmt");
        decimal Profitprice; 
        if (Decimal.TryParse(lblAmt.Text, Profitprice) ) {
             totProfit += Profitprice;
        }
    }
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        Label lblTotalAmt = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblTotalAmt");
        lblTotalAmt.Text = totProfit.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This may be because your `lblAmt` may contains a value that is not valid for decimal. So make sure your value should be parse to decimal. So for safer side use `Decimal.TryParse` like this

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
  Label lblAmt = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblAmt");
  decimal Profitprice = 0;
  if(Decimal.TryParse(lblAmt.Text, out Profitprice));
  {
     totProfit += Profitprice;
  }
}
```